# How can I provide index page differently for each user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, cancancan

How can I make the index page different for each user?

```
<% if can? :edit, :destroy, :new %>
      <td><%= ? %></td>
<% end %>
```

---

I'm using Gem 'cancancan'.

I want to provide the index page differently for each user so that only the author can check the posts.

How should I fill out the code at the '?' location?

Comment: Surely just:

    `<% current_user.posts.each do |post| %>;
      <td><%= post.whatever_content_you_want %></td>;
    <% end %>`? This question is a little unclear - if you can expand a little, I'm sure people will be able to offer more help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly your goal is, but it seems like you want each user to have a own index page and that its only accessible for this user?

You could either create a association and render only the post from the user with

`if user_signed_in? && !@user.associated_model.nil?`

and then simply loop trough the record via:

```
@user.associated_model.each do |u|
```

However, its even more organized if you create nested resources. In this case, each user will have a full CRUD function on their own. So a own index page, edit page, new page etc. You create a nested resources inside routes.rb with:

```
resources :users do
  resources :books 
end
```

Now each user will have a book CRUD function.

Inside your books controller, you can for example write down for the index show page:

```
def index

 @user = User.find(params[:user_id]
 @book = @user.books

end
```

inside your view file you can then simply render each book for each user:

```
<% @user.books.each do |b| %>

 <%= b.title %>

<% end %>
```

because of the nested resources, you have to add to your form two models, the first one is the model that is your root, in this case the user, the second variable is the second resource, in this case the books. So simply write down:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @book] do |f| %>

 <%= f.text_field :title %>

<% end %>
```

This is just for a showcase, of course you have to adjust the resources and model to the ones in your project, the book association was and is just for showcase purposes. If you have any further questions, let me know!

Greetings!